# struct pointer being optimized out using -O3 option

Tags: c, optimization, struct

It seems to be impossible to debug optimized code. I've spent way too long trying to outsmart the compiler. I am having a hard time doing a simple check if my struct is null or not due to the compiler optimizing my code, don't get me wrong I do want to keep the -O3 option if possible to speed up my code, but if I keep getting so many bugs due to compiler optimizations I might just turn it off.

I have a thread which will try to dequeue struct entries from a array and put them into a database but for some reason the struct is getting optimized out.

```
void *queue_func(void *param){
    LogArgs* largs;
    pthread_mutex_t *mx = (pthread_mutex_t*) param;

    InitQueue();
    while(!needQuit(mx)){
        if((largs = Dequeue()) != NULL){ // the boolean result is true here
            interrupt_log(largs->event, largs->rawtime); // yet largs is NULL here!!!
        }
        usleep(50000);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

For reference here is the Dequeue function and struct:

```
LogArgs* Dequeue(){
    LogArgs* largs;

    if(isEmpty()) return NULL;
    else{
        largs = &queue[++head % MAX_SIZE];
        return largs;
    }
}
```

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    time_t *rawtime;
    char event[129];
} LogArgs;
```

Is there any way to prevent largs from being optimized out?

Comment: try adding `volatile` in front of `LogArgs* largs;` in the `Dequeue()` function.  That should prevent it from being optimized out.

Comment: Put the `queue_func()` and `Dequeue()` functions in a separate file and compile it with a lower level of optimization (or even without optimization).

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that might lead to compiler optimizing out `largs`. How did you conclude `the boolean result is true here` is the case there?

Comment: @rost0031 it seems to work with volatile, thanks! @squeamishossifrage I already have the functions in different files, would lower optimization for those files be better than using volatile? @BlueMoon taking a look in gdb I set a breakpoint at the `interrupt_log(largs->event, largs->rawtime);` line thus it will only break if the boolean expression is true. Then using `p largs` it is clear that the result is 0x0!

Comment: `largs` is unlikely to actually be NULL in the case you have described. That would mean that the compiler has generated incorrect code. It's more likely a common debugging phenomenon. gdb can only go by the information it has. With optimisations on it just means gdb can't get the real value of `largs` at that point (e.g. because its value was in a register that has been re-used for something else at that point that you examine it).

Comment: It is not the struct which is being optimized away, it is lars, which is a pointer. That implies that the compiler has come up with a different way of keeping track of the pointer without storing it in memory. What makes you think it is NULL?

Comment: Is the program actually misbehaving or are you just going by what you see in a debugger?

Comment: @AlanAu Yeah that makes sense, I tried to look at the disassembly yesterday but since it was optimized and I was quite tired, it was extremely hard to understand. @rici You're right, it is just a pointer which value is 0 from the beginning and since the compiler probably keeps the pointer in a register it is unavailable at the time to the debugger, which will explain why it is read as 0 after the comparsion. @MattMcNabb It is in fact misbehaving, because instead of actually calling `interrupt_log` when there is an item available in the queue it will always call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debugging with full optimization is - as you already noticed - just a pain. And tricking with `volatile`, etc. does not help much, it might even be faster to disable optimizations completely, as `volatile` inhibits the compiler to put a variable into a register (for instance).

Try [`-Og`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.5/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) (since gcc 4.8). That should enable optimizations which do not interfere with debugging.

If you have data structures between two threads, you **have** to tell the compiler they are special. However, for modern multi-CPU systems with caches, etc. `volatile` is of little to no use for application-layer code. Use atomic types (`stdatomic.h`) instead - fully supported since gcc 4.9. These include barriers (aka fences) to guarantee correct ordering of the accesses.

Comment: that's really useful thanks, should I use -Og together with atomic types or can I use -O3?

Comment: @Linus: optimization shall not change the behaviour of the abstract machine. Atomics has nothing to do with optimization or debugging, but is required to ensure a defined behaviour when using multiple threads (synchronisation). Many programs without such just happen to work by chance. And most of them will fail from time to time due to race conditions, etc. I mostly mentioned atomics, as you did not show the whole code (no need for the question), so you have to decide yourself if they are required or not. Higher-level mechanisms like the mutex you use already include such mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Dequeue()` function is in the same translation unit (roughly speaking, the same `.c` file), then it is quite likely that it is being inlined into `queue_func()`, so the code of `queue_func()` ends up looking more like this:

```
void *queue_func(void *param)
{
    LogArgs* largs;
    pthread_mutex_t *mx = (pthread_mutex_t*) param;

    InitQueue();
    while (!needQuit(mx))
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) // the boolean result is true here
        {
            largs = &queue[++head % MAX_SIZE];
            interrupt_log(largs->event, largs->rawtime); // yet largs is NULL here!!!
        }
        usleep(50000);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

...and then the compiler sees that there's no point in setting `largs` at all, because it can just convert that to this:

```
void *queue_func(void *param)
{
    LogArgs* largs;
    pthread_mutex_t *mx = (pthread_mutex_t*) param;

    InitQueue();
    while (!needQuit(mx))
    {
        if (!isEmpty()) // the boolean result is true here
        {
            size_t temp_index = ++head % MAX_SIZE;
            interrupt_log(queue[temp_index].event, queue[temp_index].rawtime); // yet largs is NULL here!!!
        }
        usleep(50000);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

...and now it should be obvious why `largs` can be NULL - the compiler doesn't bother writing to it at all, because the code has the same effect without it.

Debugging optimised code can be difficult.  You can either compile without optimisation and try to reproduce the problem, or examine the machine code and registers in the debugger while debugging the optimised code.

Comment: that makes sense, however why is `isEmpty()` returning false? Or maybe it isn't but really it should be empty at that point! Because it is called immediately after start-up of the program. It returns whether or not `(head == tail)`, which should be true after `InitQueue()` is called which initializes `head` and `tail` with -1.

Comment: Nevermind, it is probably because I did in fact put Dequeue into a separate  source file, which probably means it does something else than inlining the code.